# How to verify the error in ILogger.LogMessage?

Tags: c#, moq

I have an error Logged in ILogger.

```
ILogger.LogMessage(Error, "Steps failed", System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
```

I need to verify in my unit test if the same error in thrown. How can I achieve this. Here is what I'm trying to do using Mock.

```
var expectedException = @""Steps failed", System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture);

_Mocklogger.Verify(
                x =>
                    x.LogMessage(LogSeverity.Error, expectedException,
                        new System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException(expectedException)), Times.Once);
```

However this failed with error :

```
Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x => x.LogMessage(LogSeverity.Error, "Parameter count mismatch.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Moq is trying to match the `TargetParameterCountException` by reference but, as the parameter in the verify statement is a newed instance, it will never match.

Try,

```
_Mocklogger.Verify(x =>x.LogMessage(LogSeverity.Error, 
                                    expectedException,
              It.IsAny<System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException>()),
                                    Times.Once);
```

to see if this is the problem.
If Moq matches against the above and if you need to ensure that the message in the exception is correct, you will need to put in a function to check the exception contents.

**e.g.**

```
_Mocklogger.Verify(x =>x.LogMessage(LogSeverity.Error, 
                                    expectedException,
  It.Is<System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException>(CheckException)),
                                    Times.Once);


private static bool CheckException(System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException ex){
    //...
}
```